# Laravel echo doesn't receive messages from Pusher server

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pusher, laravel-echo

I am trying to develop a chat application with Laravel, pusher, and Laravel-echo. I finished all the coding parts. when I send a message from chat UI, The event class return that message to the pusher server. But it doesn't receive to Laravel echo.

Vue component which is listing to event

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    mounted() {

        this.listen();

    },

    methods:{
        listen() {
            Echo.private('project.1')
                .listen('ChatNotification', (comment) => {

                    console.log(comment)
                  });
        }
    },
});
```

ChatNotification event class

```
class ChatNotification implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;

    public function __construct(AccountantChatMsg  $AccMsg)
    {
        $this->message=$AccMsg;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('project.1');
    }
}
```

Broadcast service provider was uncommented.
Pusher was configured with App-id,key, secrete and cluster.

No errors are showing in console or web page.